# "Do you wish to open or save this file" when php page runs too long

Tags: php, timeout, exec

I have a php script that runs for about 3 minutes.  I used:

```
set_time_limit(600);
echo "blah";
exec("mycommand.exe");
```

I know the code runs, because it's zipping a folder.  However, after a few minutes, IE gives "Do you want to open or save this file?".

The script has some echo commands.  If I remove the exec() command (it calls a zip utility), the code runs fine, and I see a regular webpage with the outputs of the echo commands.

If I add the exec() command back in, it gives the "Do you want to open...".  The command in the exec() has no output.  It just zips a folder.

Any ideas what could cause this?  I thought it might be a timeout issue, but the set_time_limit() doesn't seem to fix it.  I'm thinking it might be a browser setting, or Apache setting?

Comment: If you tell IE "Yes, I want to save this file" then what are the contents of the downloaded file? I cannot find the documentation at this exact moment but I think I read somewhere that Apache puts a hard limit on publicly accessible server scripts equal to 300 seconds. Web scripts running longer than 10 seconds are bad enough so something running longer than 300 seconds is absurd. It's kind of like a built in defense mechanism so that your server doesn't easily get overloaded. Scripts called via command line do not have a timeout as far as I know.

Comment: The file is empty, and the file extension is .php.  It's timing out after 120 seconds.  I searched my php.ini for any mention of "120", or "12", and I can't find any timeout setting.

Comment: It's probably an Apache setting. Do you have the ability to change Apache configurations?

Comment: yes, I looked in httpd.conf and the .conf files for the virtual hosts.  I searched for the number "120", "12", and "13", and the word "time".  I can't seem to find any setting that might cause this.

Comment: The more I think about it, I think it is actually hard-coded into the Apache build.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  It's not a huge issue for me.  I found that even if I hit Cancel on the download, the script seems to run to completion, so I guess that's all that matters for me.